# More efficient method for string parsing?

Tags: vb.net

First part of the code is to retrieve data from the web. It takes only a part of the second to complete the request. Second part of the code is to split data so that parts of data can be shown in different labels and it takes around 5-6 second to complete this operation?
Why is that? Can it be done faster?

First part of the code (textbox1 key down event)

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        TextBox1.Text = UCase(TextBox1.Text)
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            GoTo exx
        Else

            Dim strURL As String
            Dim strSymbol As String = TextBox1.Text
            strURL = " http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?" & _
                 "s=" & strSymbol & _
                 "&d=t" & _
            "&f=snl1pmwvj1l1"

            MessageBox.Show(RequestWebData(strURL))
```

Second part of the code and functions :

```
  Label24.Text = (GetName2(RequestWebData(strURL), 3))
            Dim myText = Label24.Text
            Dim dIndex = myText.IndexOf("Inc.")
            If (dIndex > -1) Then
                Label24.Text = (Strings.Left(Label24.Text, dIndex + 4))
            Else
                Label24.Text = (Label24.Text)
            End If
            Dim myText2 = Label24.Text
            Dim dIndex2 = myText2.IndexOf("Common")
            If (dIndex2 > -1) Then
                Label24.Text = (Label24.Text.Replace("Common", ""))
            Else
                Label24.Text = (Label24.Text)
            End If
            Label6.Text = (GetName(RequestWebData(strURL), 4))
            Label6.Text = (GetName3(Label6.Text, 1))
            Label6.Text = FormatNumber(Label6.Text, 2)

            Label17.Text = (GetName(RequestWebData(strURL), 5))
            Label21.Text = (GetName(RequestWebData(strURL), 7))
            Dim x As String = GetName(RequestWebData(strURL), 8)
            Label30.Text = GetName3(x, 1)
            Label30.Text = FormatNumber(Label30.Text, 0)
            Label32.Text = GetName3(x, 2)

            TextBox2.Focus()

 Function GetName(ByVal LineIn As String, ByVal i As Integer) As String
    'Dim x As Integer
    Return LineIn.Split(""",")(i)
End Function
Function GetName2(ByVal LineIn As String, ByVal i As Integer) As String
    'Dim x As Integer
    Return LineIn.Split("""")(i)
End Function
Function GetName3(ByVal LineIn As String, ByVal i As Integer) As String
    'Dim x As Integer
    Return LineIn.Split(",")(i)
End Function
```

Maybe it is so slow because of these three functions that I am using to split data?

Comment: It seems like you are calling `RequestWebData(strURL)` 5 times in the second part of your code. Are each of these calls taking 1 second each? That would explain the 5 to 6 seconds. Can you not store the result in a variable or does it change each call?

Comment: Thanks you so much. Never would have noticed that.